# 4th order Runge Kutta method ODE problem

Tags: numerical-methods, discrete-calculus

This is a question from a test that I failed to pass and it really bugs, wish that someone could explain it to me.Consider the differential equation

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{2x}$
​

This is a separable O.D.E., so the solutions are of the form

$x(t) = \sqrt{t + C}$
​

where C is a constant. Imposing the initial condition x(1) = 1 fixes C = 0. Then we have $x(2) = \sqrt{2}$.

Use Euler's method with h = 1/2 to find an approximation to $\sqrt{2}$. Provide a numeric answer rounded to two decimal places.The answer to this is very obviously 1.45. The next part is issue:
Apply the fourth order Runge-Kutta method:
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} ​  &=x_n ​  +  1/6 ​  (k_1 ​  +2k_2 ​  +2k_3 ​+k_4)
\\\hline
k_1 ​ & =hf(x_n ​  ,t_n ​  )
\\
k_2 ​  &=hf(x_n ​  +  1/2 ​  k_1 ​  ,t_n ​  +  1/2 ​  h)
\\
k_3 ​ & =hf(x_n ​  +  1/2 ​  k_2 ​  ,t_n ​  +  1/2 ​  h)
\\
k_4 ​  &=hf(x_n ​  +k_3 ​  ,t_n ​  +h)
\end{align}

Apply it, with $h=1$, to the initial value problem of the previous Question to find a (better) approximation to $\sqrt{2}$
​ Provide a numeric answer rounded to five decimal places. The following is the calculation that was rejected, I didn't understand why it was incorrect:
$$
x=\sqrt{t};\:\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\:;
\\
t_0=1,\:x_0=\sqrt{t};x_0=\sqrt{1};x\left(1\right)=1\:h=1;
\\
\:y\left(1\right)=1;\:x_0=1;\:y_0=1\:h=1;
\\
k_1=1⋅\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1}}=\frac{1}{2}=0.5;\:
\\
k_2=1⋅f\left(1+\frac{1}{2}⋅\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{2}⋅1\right)=f\left(\frac{5}{3},\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{1}{6}=0.40825;\:
\\
k_3=1⋅f\left(1+\frac{1}{2}⋅\left(0.40825\right)1+\frac{1}{2}⋅1\right)=f⋅\left(1.20412,1.5\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1.5}}=0.40825;\:
\\
k_4=0.35355;\:
\\
x_1=1+\frac{1}{6}\left(0.5+2⋅0.40825+2⋅0.40825+0.35355\right)=1.41442
$$ – Please, could someone illuminate my mistake or point me in the direction of a correct answer? I love math, although I am probably to dum to get it right, please, don't downvote!

Comment: What numerical values did you get for the ki

Comment: I calculated k1= 0.5

Comment: Why not give all your k k1 is ok

Comment: Any corrective input would be appreciated, but I already know its the wrong answer, I just don't see why

Comment: You always use f(x,t) but it is only f(x).  since $x'=f(x)=1/2\sqrt(x)  so  k_2=f(1,25)≠1/\sqrt(6)$, it seems you use instead of f(x) in the De the solution? but you want an approximation of the solution at t=2!

Comment: The function $f(x,t)$ is $1/(2x)$ here, not $1/(2\sqrt{t})$. Although these give the same function of $t$ when $x=\sqrt{t}$, numerical methods won't react to them in the same way. That seems like the first problem, although it might just be a matter of notation.

Comment: To your previous comment, thisd just how I was taught to do it. I though it is just a matter of notation

Answer (score 2):

You ran RK4 for $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}},x(1)=1$. This ODE IVP has the same exact solution as yours, but nonetheless changing the equation in this way changes the numerical solution a little bit.

Answer (score -2):

This is the correct solution I found online, monkey see monkey copy. The answer is $k1=\frac{1}{2};k2=\frac{2}{5};k3=\frac{5}{12};k4=\frac{6}{17};1+\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)+2\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)+\frac{6}{17}\right)$ =1.41438 Does nothing for my understanding though

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).